# how can I scrape a elements and store text, href and src and then use them in my Django template

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape a elements and store text, href and src and then use them in my template

```
google = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(google.content, 'html.parser')
d = bs.title.string

a_links = bs.findAll('a', 'entry')

links = []
for link in a_links:
    links.append((
        link.text,
        link.get('href'),
        link.get('src')
    )
)

context = {
    "links": links,
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I had it like this

```
links = []
for link in a_links:
    links.append((
        link.text
    )
)

context = {
    "links": links,
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and I followed someones suggestion to change it to this

```
links = [link.text for link in a_links]

context = {
    "links": links,
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

this does not work

```
 links = [link.text,link.get('href'),link.get('src') for link in a_links]
```

whats the correct syntax to scrape a elements, store the text, href and src and then out put it in my django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you want to store each triple values. For example, you can store them in a python dictionary :

```
links = [{'text': link.text,
          'href': link.get('href'),
          'src': link.get('src')
          } for link in a_links]
```

which later can be accessed using the dictionary key :

```
for link in links:
    print link['text'], link['href'], link['src']
```

Comment: hey, That works. and all I have to do in my template is {% for e in entries %} {{e.text}}<br>
    {{e.href}}<br>
    {{e.src}}<br> and I get what I need

Comment: ah sure, that's the syntax in django template! Haven't used django that much so I didn't remember the syntax off the top of my head (actually, I missed that the question is about django as well :D)